# Undefined reference to Py_Initialize()

Tags: python, c++, c

I was trying to embed some Python into a C program, but first I was testing some elementary operations as seen in the following code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hello world')");
    Py_Finalize();

    // Some C code
}
```

It turns out that (a) the makefile does build well the program when commenting out the Python-related lines (Py_Initialize, PyRun_SingleString, Py_Finalize), (b) however, when adding the Python lines, the build returns the following error:

```bash
g++ -o program program.cpp -lm -std=c++11 -O3 -I/usr/include/python3.6m/
/tmp/ccgiujXn.o: In function `main':
program.cpp:(.text.startup+0x62): undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'
program.cpp:(.text.startup+0x70): undefined reference to `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
program.cpp:(.text.startup+0x75): undefined reference to `Py_Finalize'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'exec_program' failed
make: *** [exec_program] Error 1
```

Do you know why this error occurs? I thought that the Python.h header was correctly added, but it does not seem to be the case when adding the Python lines.  My makefile is:

```
exec_program:  program.cpp
    g++ -o program program.cpp -lm -std=c++11 -O3 -I/usr/include/python3.6m/
    ./program
    rm program
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, g++ 7.4.0, Python 3.6.9 (/usr/lib/) and 3.7.6 (/home/anaconda3/lib).

Sorry if you find the question is reiterative, but I thought no other post had a solution for my problem.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to link the library in with `-l`

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've supposed the solution had to be this simple. I've edited the Makefile to


    exec_program:  program.cpp
 g++ -o program program.cpp -std=c++11 -O3 -I/usr/include/python3.6m/ -lpython3.6m -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lrt -lm
 ./program
 rm program


and it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much. Did `-lpython3.11` and it worked

Comment: For maximum clarity, this is the command `gcc mainEncoder.c -I/usr/include/python3.8 -lpython3.8  -o m.o && ./m.o

Answer (score 1):

You should not compile your module as stand alone executable, but rather as shared library object `*.so`, so objects line `Py_Initialize` will be avaliable at run time. The suggested by documentation way is

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('demo',
                   define_macros = [('MAJOR_VERSION', '1'),
                                 ('MINOR_VERSION', '0')],
                   include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include'],
                   libraries = ['tcl83'],
                   library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib'],
                   sources = ['demo.c'])

setup (name = 'PackageName',
      version = '1.0',
      description = 'This is a demo package',
      author = 'Martin v. Loewis',
      author_email = 'martin@v.loewis.de',
      url = 'https://docs.python.org/extending/building',
      long_description = '''
This is really just a demo package.
''',
      ext_modules = [module1])
```

The `distutils` module will generate correct `gcc` command for you.

You can read more about building python modules at official documentation https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html#building

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This was not yet something I needed, but I would definitely do more of the official documentation reading stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` library directory and the `python3.6m` library:

```
g++ -o program program.cpp -lm -std=c++11 -O3 -I/usr/include/python3.6m/ -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lpython3.6m
```